# Mapbox Bug with Zoom Control

Tags: mapbox, directions

I’m using mapbox.directions v0.3.0.  I have come across a bug with the Zoom Control when using Internet Explorer only.  It works fine with Edge, Chrome, and Firefox.  I have the following layout:

```
<div id="pnlMapControl">
    <div id="pnlRoutePane">
        <div id="divRouteInputs"></div>
        <div id="divRouteErrors"></div>
        <div id="divRouteDirections">
            <div id="divAlternateRoutes"></div>
            <div id="divRouteInstructions"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pnlMap"></div>
    <div id="pnlStatusBar">
        <span id="lblStatus">Status</span>
        <span id="lblLatLon" style="float:right">LatLon</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

pnlMapControl is a top level container control.  pnlMap is the container for the Mapbox map.  pnlRoutePane is where I want to have my input controls and display the instructions.  I would prefer to keep the controls separate from the map container.  pnlRoutePane is positioned on the left (and its visibility is toggled on and off so it is only visible when working with a route), and pnlMap is on the right.

My issue is, in IE11, when I click the zoom control on the map, it causes the parent pnlMapControl container to move left the width of pnlRoutePane and displays the Mapbox map at left position 0.  All other browsers work without this issue.  Is there something that can be done so that it will also work with IE?

Thanks in advance.  My CSS is below:

```
    #pnlMapControl {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        top: 60px;
        bottom: 0px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    #pnlRoutePane {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        width: 300px;
        top: 33px;
        bottom: 20px;
        background-color: lightseagreen;
        display: none;
    }
    #pnlMap {
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: lightyellow;
    }
    #pnlStatusBar {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    #lblStatus {
        margin-left: 5px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #lblLatLon {
        margin-right: 5px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #divRouteInputs {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 280px;
        height: 80px;
        background-color:yellow;
    }

    #divRouteErrors {
        position: absolute;
        top: 120px;
        left: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    }

    #divRouteDirections {
        position: absolute;
        top: 120px;
        left: 10px;
        bottom: 0px;
        overflow: auto;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }
```

Comment: I changed pnlMap to absolute positioning and that fixed the issue.  However, when the pnlMap (map container) is made smaller the fitBounds() does not work properly as it seems to think it still has the full width...

Comment: SOLVED:  In addition to making pnlMap absolute positioned (somehow this was better for IE), I called map.invalidateSize() and now the fitBounds works properly.

Comment: Good thing you've solved this, it would be even better, if you come across inconsistencies like this, and that you've tested it through and through, that you mention this in their issue tracker. Let them know something's wrong: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-directions.js/issues Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: I did report it to Mapbox, but you make a good point about the issue traker.  Thanks for helping me learn how to work with GitHub.